# Handling the situation where you need to update 2 objects simultaneously

Tags: parse-platform

I have 2 objects: **Post** and **Comment** These objects behave normally, like how a forum has a post and several comments.

The **Post** object has a `commentCount` that holds the number of comments **Post**. When a user makes a comment to the post, I need to do the following:

1. Save the **Comment** object
2. Increment the `commentCount` field in **Post**

Thus, I need to do 2 `saveInBackground` operations. However, if something goes wrong to one of the saves, I will have a mismatch between `commentCount` and the actual number of comments. What is a method to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

If the comment has a pointer to Post you wouldn't need to save the count, but instead Querying it. You would avoid mismatches.

`query.countObjects() //synchronously` or

`query.countObjectsInBackground() //asynchronously`

I don't know about NoSQL databases, like Parse, but in a regular one you usually want to avoid to save fields that can be calculated.

Comment: According to Parse docs, they discourage using those two operations. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide under performance/avoid count operations

Comment: Ah, haven't seen that before. Well spotted!

Comment: Couldn't you nestle the two save operations then? Like the first one increments the commentCount in post, and in that completion block, if it succeeds you trigger the save for the comment. If the comment object couldn't be saved you trigger a decrement save for the count in that completion block. It might not be 100% safe, if both the comment save and the decrement fail.

Comment: That was something I considered as well, but it doesn't solve the problem. Let's say you were able to save the increment, and control is currently in the completion block. If the net drops or some other error came up when the completion block has control, it will still fail to save the comment whilst incrementing the comment count. 

What a dilemma :c